# Ubuntu unable to update and upgrade to 14.04: GPG Error

Tags: 13.10, apt, updates

I have been looking around the net for solutions but I just cannot get rid of this error.

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease                               
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                                   
Get:1 http://glug.nith.ac.in saucy InRelease                                   
Get:2 http://qgis.org saucy InRelease [3,187 B]                                
100% [1 InRelease gpgv 9,491 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [WaSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/glug.nith.ac.in_ubuntu_archives_dists_sauIgn http://glug.nith.ac.in saucy InRelease                                     
E: GPG error: http://glug.nith.ac.in saucy InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

EDIT: This particular error disappeared upon changing the server to the main Ubuntu server. There were a few errors with 404 not found, and I removed those ppas from the software list.
On a sidenote, I recently removed and purged qgis so don't know what its doing there.

Comment: Or, [Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) reaches End of Life on July 17 2014](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2014-June/000185.html).

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem. Run following command to resolve it.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: It may be worked in your case, but is really not indicated to delete  last lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list` just like this without to have any idea about their content.

Comment: It could usely be normal commen the last ones because it is the lastly, and it tame there just had been installed in the repository.